# Alternate row colors in javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a table which have alternate row colors, for example the first row is red, the second is green, the third is red and so on.
Written this code so far and got stuck, don't know what to put in if statement.

```
var color = "red";
var outputString = "<table border=1 width=50%>"; 
outputString = outputString + "<tr><td>a</td><td>a^2</td><td>a^3</td></tr>";    
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
if (i%2 == 0) {

} else {

}
outputString += "<tr class=" + color + ">" + "<td>" + i + "</td>" + "<td>" + i * i + "</td>" + "<td>" + i * i * i + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    } 
outputString += "</table>"; 
document.write(outputString);
```

Comment: I would recommend you use jQuery for this if possible. Its just one line of code using jQuery.

Comment: where is the table code ?

Comment: have an option of JQuery?

Comment: sorry, here it is, in javascript.

Answer (score 15):

Here is the pure css version,

```
table tr:nth-child(odd) td{
}
table tr:nth-child(even) td{
}
```

And here is the jQuery solution for the same,

```
$(function(){
   $("table tr:even").addClass("evenClassName");
   $("table tr:odd").addClass("oddClassName");
});
```

Here is the pure JavaScript solution,

```
function altrows(firstcolor,secondcolor)
{
    var tableElements = document.getElementsByTagName("table") ;
    for(var j = 0; j < tableElements.length; j++)
    {
        var table = tableElements[j] ;

        var rows = table.getElementsByTagName("tr") ;
        for(var i = 0; i <= rows.length; i++)
        {
            if(i%2==0){
                rows[i].style.backgroundColor = firstcolor ;
            }
            else{
                rows[i].style.backgroundColor = secondcolor ;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Congratulations for providing a pure JavaScript answer! (Though in your second for, it should be i < rows.length)

Comment: I tried using ` rows[i].style.backgroundColor` but i get `Cannot set property 'backgroundColor' of undefined. I'm pretty sure my table row is not empty, and that the error is being thrown by `style`. Has the syntax changed?

Answer (score 4):

Use this(JQUERY WAY):-

```
$(document).ready(function()
{
  $("table#tblid tr:even").css("background-color", "color code");
  $("table#tblid tr:odd").css("background-color", "color code");
});
```

Here is the JavaScript way of doing it:-

```
var tblrows = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i=0;i<tblrows.length;i++){
    if(i%2==0) tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#f22000';
    else tblrows[i].style.backgroundColor = '#a02141';
}
```

**[JS FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/ZKnGe/)**

Comment: Thank you, but I was thinking if it would be possible to do only with javascript and CSS?

Comment: What if I want to have a column a red, two columns blue, a column red, two colums blue, and so on? Can you help me with this, please?

Answer (score 3):

use this, it will apply for all tables too

```
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
    if(i%2==0) tr[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/CME64/XeA7w/1/)

if you want to highlight the trs that have at least a td element inside use this :

```
var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
    if(i%2==0 && tr[i].getElementsByTagName('td').length) tr[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
}
```

Comment: What if I want to have a column a red, two columns blue, a column red, two colums blue, and so on? Can you help me with this, please?

Comment: `var tr = document.getElementsByTagName('tr');

for(i=0;i<tr.length;i++){
    if(i%3==0) tr[i].style.backgroundColor = 'red';
    else tr[i].style.backgroundColor = 'blue';
}`

Answer (score 1):

Here is an alternative pure JavaScript + CSS solution.

```
// get all even rows
var evenRows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(even)');
// get all odd rows
var oddRows = document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(odd)');
// set even rows background color
evenRows.forEach((evenRow) => { evenRow.style.backgroundColor = 'myEvenRowColor'; });
// set odd rows background color
oddRows.forEach((oddRow) => { oddRow.style.backgroundColor = 'myOddRowColor'; });
```

This takes advantage of JavaScript's [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/querySelectorAll) and [forEach](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/forEach) functions and [CSS selectors](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Selectors).

The above code can also be written in two lines:

```
document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(even)').forEach((evenRow) => { evenRow.style.backgroundColor = 'myEvenRowColor'; });
document.querySelectorAll('tr:nth-child(odd)').forEach((oddRow) => { oddRow.style.backgroundColor = 'myOddRowColor'; });
```

Answer (score 0):

Using just your code as a basis you'll want to do this in the if statement:

```
var color_even = "red";
var color_odd = "green";
var outputString = "<table border=1 width=50%>"; 
outputString = outputString + "<tr><td>a</td><td>a^2</td><td>a^3</td></tr>";    
for (var i = 1; i <= 5; i++ ) {
if (i%2 == 0) {
    color_used = color_even;
} else {
    color_used = color_odd;
}
outputString += "<tr class=\"" + color_used + "\">" + "<td>" + i + "</td>" + "<td>" + i * i + "</td>" + "<td>" + i * i * i + "</td>" + "</tr>";
    } 
outputString += "</table>"; 
document.write(outputString);
```

Comment: What if I want to have a column a red, two columns blue, a column red, two colums blue, and so on? Can you help me with this, please?